# can somehow change the callback function name?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Hey, I am doing to AJAX call to "flickr.interestingness.getList" to get the interesting pictures and this is my AJAX call.

```
function getPhoto()
{
$.ajax("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&format=json&api_key=fbfe07eb3cc28814df5bbc0313cdd521", 
        {
        dataType: "jsonp",
        //jsonp: false, jsonFlickrApi: "jsonpcallback",
        jsonpCallback: "jsonFlickrApi",
        });
}

function jsonFlickrApi(data)
{
alert(data.photos.photo);
}
```

and here "JsonFlickrApi" is the pre-defined function from Flickr that wraps the json object which has a bunch of photos. My question is could I somehow override the pre-defined function, "jsonFlickApi" and name the callback function something other than "jsonFlickrApi", I thought the jsonp parameter is supposed to do that after I read the jQuery documentation but just failed to change it.or I dont quite understand what the jsonp parameter does in jQuery AJAX call. thank you

Comment: I'm wondering why do you want to replace it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close. This works perfectly:

```
function getPhoto() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&format=json&api_key=fbfe07eb3cc28814df5bbc0313cdd521",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}

getPhoto();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Ag2Dz/)

As the [documentation describes](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html), you can set your own callback name with the `jsoncallback` parameter. Hence we have to set `jsonp: 'jsoncallback'`. In the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can find that it is recommended to let jQuery choose a callback name. Just set the `success` callback and you are done.

Comment: yeah, I guess what I dont understand is that since I can set my own call back name, I am supposed to name it whatever I want. right? I've tried do it like this jsonp: 'jsonpcallback', but it throws an error saying jsonFlickrApi is not defined. how so? Thank you

Comment: @ClinteneyHui: I don't know what else you are doing. The code above works. Yes, you can name it whatever you want but you don't have to. Why not let jQuery handle it?

Comment: I got it. misunderstood a little bit. Thanx

Comment: Something to note here. Setting `jsonp` in the ajax object changes the **key** of the query string parameter for jsonp. Setting `jsonpCallback` sets the **value** of that key.

For example: `{jsonp: 'foo', jsonpCallback: 'bar'}` would result in the url looking like: `...?foo=bar...`

Answer (score 2):

From the [Flickr API docs](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html):

> If you just want the raw JSON, with no
>   function wrapper, add the parameter
>   nojsoncallback with a value of 1 to
>   your request.
>
> To define your own callback function
>   name, add the parameter jsoncallback
>   with your desired name as the value.

```
nojsoncallback=1    -> {...}
jsoncallback=wooYay -> wooYay({...});
```

Example:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.interestingness.getList&format=json&api_key=fbfe07eb3cc28814df5bbc0313cdd521&jsoncallback=myCallbackFun
```

Returns:

```
myCallbackFun({"photos":{"page":1, "pages":5, "perpage":100, "total":500, "photo":[{"id":"5623656271", "owner":"50725098@N08", "secret":"b67514798d", "server":"5143", "farm":6, "title":"Defying Gravity!!!", "ispublic":1, "isfriend":0, "isfamily":0}, {"id":"5624056667", "owner":"51832166@N03", "secret":"57ffca018d", "server":"5301", "farm":6, "title":"Navy Officers: Pearl Harbor", "i...
```